# How to use any video bitstream from external accessory for preview?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, external-accessory

In iOS, To preview the video, I found that I should use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with an instance of `AVCaptureSession`. For example,

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = <#Get a capture session>;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView *aView = <#The view in which to present the layer#>;
previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds;
[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

And `AVCaptureSession` needs some `AVCaptureDevices` and `AVCaptureDeviceInputs`

For example,

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
if (audioInput) {
     [captureSession addInput:audioInput];
}
else {
     // Handle the failure.
}
```

I referred to apple development documents for the above examples.
But, whether the devices are audio or video, all examples uses only built-in camera, and mic of iPhone/iPad.

My project doesn't use built-in camera and mic but external accessories which supports MP4 and is already MFi compliant.

I've already tested MFi authentication and identification and MP4 bitstream coming to iPhone devices using external accessory framework.

But, I have no idea how I can use bitstream from external accessory (instead of built-in camera and mic) for displaying preview on UI view of iPhone.
Is there any expert in this kind of problems ?

Comment: Hi, did you get any help from anywhere? i have same requirement. Could you please help me the method that you accepted?